# pandas: create new column group by others

Tags: python, pandas

i want to create new column that will calculate a ratio groupby date and count like shown below in the result of my new column **new**.

```
   date    count    place       moy       new
2021-07-04  396       NY        30.     30/(30+10+20+40)
2021-07-04  396       OX        10.     10/(30+10+20+40)
2021-07-04  396       CA        20      20/(30+10+20+40)
2021-07-04  396       LA        40      40/(30+10+20+40)
2021-07-05  592       NY        30.     30/(30+50+10+30)
2021-07-05  592       OX        50.     50/120
2021-07-05  592       NY        10.     10/120
2021-07-05  592       OX        30.     30/12O
```

Comment: Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 1):

Try via `groupby()` and `transform()`:

```
df['new']=df['moy']/df.groupby(['date','count'])['moy'].transform('sum')
#OR
df['new']=df['moy'].div(df.groupby(['date','count'])['moy'].transform('sum'))
```

If needed you can round the values by using `round()` method:

```
df['new']=df['new'].round(2)
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output

Comment: You don't need `transform('sum')`, you can invoke `sum()` directly on the groupby series.

Comment: @ifly6 Sir,It was needed to perform division If I do `df.groupby(['date','count'])['moy'].sum()` then I need to map values(which make the answer more complicated) for  performing division operation